# vuejs : npm run dev not working

Tags: npm, vue.js

I have a problem with vueJs webpack , i want to run in server , with command : npm run dev . 
Nothing happing just , a list of errors : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0gWC.png)

Comment: You need to post the ***relevant*** error message directly in the question.  That said, you actually posted the least helpful piece.  You need to post the stack trace error that is located above what you've shown in the image.

Answer (score 3):

**You can use this in your command project**

```
 # npm install
 # npm run serve
```

Answer (score 0):

I use webpack vue-cli

I code and run my vue apps on android tablet
i too got the same log errors using `npm run dev`
I think it is because of the platform i am running the app(android)

**so i use**

```
webpack-dev-server --inline --hot
```

This works for me.so try running`webpack-dev-server --inline --hot` command

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it worked for me.

Just change the port number in the dev{} obj in the following file.

[your project folder]/config/index.js

By default, mine was set to 8080. Change it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command first

```
npm config set ignore-scripts false
```

And then rerun your command

```
npm run dev
```